# Pandas dataframe returns None value

Tags: python, pandas

I have to clean CSV file Data. The data that I am trying to clean is below. 
Condition: I have to add @myclinic.com.au at the end of every string where it is missing.

```
douglas@myclinic.com.au
mildura
broadford@myclinic.com.au
officer@myclinic.com.au
nowa nowa@myclinic.com.au
langsborough@myclinic.com.au
brisbane@myclinic.com.au
robertson@myclinic.com.au
logan village
ipswich@myclinic.com.au
```

The code for this is

```
    DataFrame = pandas.read_csv(ClinicCSVFile)
    DataFrame['Email'] = DataFrame['Email'].apply(lambda x: x if '@' in str(x) else str(x)+'@myclinic.com.au')
    DataFrameToCSV = DataFrame.to_csv('Temporary.csv', index = False)   
    print(DataFrameToCSV)
```

But the output that I am getting is none and I could not work on the later part of the Problem as it is generating the error below

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

which is originated by the above data frame.
Please Help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) for condition with inverting by `~` and add string to end:

```
df.loc[~df['Email'].str.endswith('@myclinic.com.au'), 'Email'] += '@myclinic.com.au'
#if need check only @
#df.loc[~df['Email'].str.contains('@'), 'Email'] += '@myclinic.com.au'
print (df)
                           Email
0        douglas@myclinic.com.au
1        mildura@myclinic.com.au
2      broadford@myclinic.com.au
3        officer@myclinic.com.au
4      nowa nowa@myclinic.com.au
5   langsborough@myclinic.com.au
6       brisbane@myclinic.com.au
7      robertson@myclinic.com.au
8  logan village@myclinic.com.au
9        ipswich@myclinic.com.au
```

For me it working nice:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Email': ['douglas@myclinic.com.au', 'mildura', 'broadford@myclinic.com.au', 'officer@myclinic.com.au', 'nowa nowa@myclinic.com.au', 'langsborough@myclinic.com.au', 'brisbane@myclinic.com.au', 'robertson@myclinic.com.au', 'logan village', 'ipswich@myclinic.com.au']})
df.loc[~df['Email'].str.contains('@'), 'Email'] += '@myclinic.com.au'
print (df)
                           Email
0        douglas@myclinic.com.au
1        mildura@myclinic.com.au
2      broadford@myclinic.com.au
3        officer@myclinic.com.au
4      nowa nowa@myclinic.com.au
5   langsborough@myclinic.com.au
6       brisbane@myclinic.com.au
7      robertson@myclinic.com.au
8  logan village@myclinic.com.au
9        ipswich@myclinic.com.au
```

Comment: df['Email'] = df.loc[~df['Email'].str.contains('@'), 'Email'] += '@myclinic.com.au'
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


I am getting this error

Comment: @Damian - It is weird, what about `df.loc[~df['Email'].str.contains('@'), 'Email'] = df.loc[~df['Email'].str.contains('@'), 'Email'] + '@myclinic.com.au'` ?

Comment: @Damian - Or maybe copy error from my post, I think if rewrite it it working nice.

Comment: @Damian - If copy my data from edited answer still same problem?

Comment: Sir, I am not understanding this error. Can you provide me with your email address? So, I can explain my problem.

Comment: @Damian - My email is in my profile, please send me email.

Comment: @Damian - There was typo, `df['Email'] = df.loc[~df['Email'].str.contains('@', na=False), 'Email'] += '@myclinic.com.au'`, need only `df.loc[~df['Email'].str.contains('@'), 'Email'] += '@myclinic.com.au'`

Comment: @Damian - But if possible `NaN`s values use `df.loc[~df['Email'].str.contains('@', na=False), 'Email'] += '@myclinic.com.au'`

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply` and `endswith`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename, names=["Email"])
print(df["Email"].apply(lambda x: x if x.endswith("@myclinic.com.au") else x+"@myclinic.com.au"))
```

**Output:**

```
0          douglas@myclinic.com.au
1          mildura@myclinic.com.au
2        broadford@myclinic.com.au
3          officer@myclinic.com.au
4        nowa nowa@myclinic.com.au
5     langsborough@myclinic.com.au
6         brisbane@myclinic.com.au
7        robertson@myclinic.com.au
8    logan village@myclinic.com.au
9          ipswich@myclinic.com.au
Name: Email, dtype: object
```